# css grid with two columns wrong size

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following grid:

[image: grid]

As you can see I have and problem with the main and right elements, because main is too big. Here es the code of my css for this grid:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.col-12 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: top-header;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  height: 70px;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: sub-header;
  background-color: #58aff4;
  height: 60px;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: main;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(max-content, 1fr);
  background-color: #0b6ba4;
  grid-column: span 9;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-column: span 3;
}
.item5 {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #ffc9c0;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content auto min-content;
  grid-template-areas:
    'top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header top-header'
    'sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header sub-header'
    'main main main main  main  main  main  right  right right right right'
    'footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer';
  height: 100vh;
}

.layout > div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

I need to have the main (item3) to be 9 column and the right (item4) to be 3 columns, but as you can see the "main" is expanding to the first two columns of the "right" element and I don't understand why?

html code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="col-12 layout">
        <div class="item1">Top Header</div>
        <div class="item2">Sub Header</div>
        <div class="item3">
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Consequatur et unde magni. Minus temporibus omnis velit. Voluptate
            similique voluptates temporibus, laudantium illo sed repudiandae
            tenetur? Nobis mollitia culpa magnam nesciunt?
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Consequatur et unde magni. Minus temporibus omnis velit. Voluptate
            similique voluptates temporibus, laudantium illo sed repudiandae
            tenetur? Nobis mollitia culpa magnam nesciunt?
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Consequatur et unde magni. Minus temporibus omnis velit. Voluptate
            similique voluptates temporibus, laudantium illo sed repudiandae
            tenetur? Nobis mollitia culpa magnam nesciunt?
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Consequatur et unde magni. Minus temporibus omnis velit. Voluptate
            similique voluptates temporibus, laudantium illo sed repudiandae
            tenetur? Nobis mollitia culpa magnam nesciunt?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">Right</div>
        <div class="item5">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: done @RishabTyagi i just update the code with the html

Comment: I have run your code and it seems to work fine.https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/PoZwdOz. Do you want to keep the width of item4 equal to the width of item3?

Comment: Most Welcome :)